# How can I launch a rails console for an app deployed on Tomcat?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tomcat, jruby

I want to get an interactive `rails console` on a deployed JRuby on Rails app on Tomcat deployed as a war file.

Comment: It would really be great if someone could tell me WHY this is not a good question instead of simply down-voting.

Answer (score 0):

its a bit tricky but possible - not going into details but here's the setup:

- setup pry-remote on server to wait for connections (on localhost)
- spawn an embed JRuby container (possible from the extracted .war content)
- the code to be executed there should simply connect via socket

Comment: Thank you! I was afraid it would not be straight forward. I'll give it a try when I have a few minutes.